# Is generator faster than while loop in python?

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, while-loop, coroutine

Question is simple, I have following code that does the same thing in python2:

```
for _ in range(n): # or xrange(),they have similar performance according to my test
    pass

i = 0
while i < n:
    i+=1
    pass
```

the for loop is faster than the while loop, when n = 1000000, each takes roughly 0.105544 and 0.2389421

1. on the surface it looks like while loop is doing the **increment** and **boundary check**, but as far as I know, the generator or iterator has to perform the same amount of hard work, so if the work done is the same, why is one faster than another?

from [python generator wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators#CA-d5466ac7b4355903187a3edcd0c340643d098bbd_1)

```
def generator(n):
    i = 0
    while i < n:
        yield i
        i += 1
```

2. in the case of an iterator, there is usually a **member function** called next, and every time it is called, it will return the *"next item in the iterable"*, to me this means **a lot of** function calls, thus huge overhead on stack (more assembly code to do push and pop stack) and based on my knowledge on coroutine (generator), it trys to circumvent this by creating a new separated stack (just like thread, it manages its own program counter), although it will no longer deal with tons of function calls, it bears the same problem as thread, namely overhead of **context switch**.
   How can the while loop be **slower** when it does not face any of the overheads I mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect the performance difference you're seeing has to do with what parts of the code are defined in Python and which are defined inside the interpreter (in C, for cpython). The calls to `next` in the `for` loop case, for instance, are going to be handled in C, and for a `range` or other built-in iterable, the implementation of the function will also be in C, so it may be pretty fast. The bounds check on the `while` loop on the other hand is a Python expression, which needs to be evaluated on each pass of the loop. Python code is almost always going to be slower than C code, so it's not too shocking that a `for` loop may be faster than a `while` loop in some situations.

Note however that both kinds of loops are probably much faster than any sort of useful work you might be doing inside of them. It is almost never worth focusing your efforts on the very small performance differences between different kinds of loops like this, rather than on larger issues like the complexity of your algorithms or the efficiency of your data structures.

The only exception might be if you've done a bunch of profiling of your code and found that a specific loop is the greatest performance bottleneck for your particular program. If that's the case, micro-optimize to your heart's content.

Comment: you are most likely correct, instead of calling `for i in range(n):` I replaced it with `for i in generator(n):` where `generator()` is the function I defined in the question, and the for loop is much slower(0.31012297). I am not very familiar with Cpython, can you elaborate on how it would treat `while,for range(),for generator()` differently?

Comment: cpython is the standard Python interpreter (from [python.org](http://www.python.org)). I would not wade too deeply in figuring out why one loop is faster than the other, since like I said in the answer, the difference is probably much much smaller than the time taken by whatever else you need to do with your code. Just use whichever kind of loop is most natural and leave optimization for when you find a specific performance problem.